# How can I add a clickable URL in a JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, url, jtextarea

I am writing an application and in that I am using `JTextArea` to display some text. Now I want to show some clickable URL in text area along with the normal text and I want if user click on the URL then the web page that URL referring to should open in new web browser window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use JEditorPane with HTMLEditorKit or JTextPane and set content type to "text/html"

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000974/java-jeditorpane-hyperlink-problem/6001047#6001047) for a quick example. ;)

Comment: I'll try that but I want to know is it possible to achieve this functionality with JTextarea?

Comment: @Sandy: I'm afraid it's not possible with JTextArea.

Comment: This will only allow you to add html content to the JTextPane/jEditorPane. I'm guessing you want the text to be converted into clickabe hyperlink(if it is) as you type.

Answer (score 2):

> ..url referring to should open in new web browser window.

```
// 1.6+
Desktop.getDesktop().browse(URI);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of opening links from JTextArea:

```
                JTextArea jtxa = new JTextArea(25,100);
                JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(jtxa);
                JPanel jp = new JPanel();
                jp.add(jsp);
                jp.setSize(100,50);

                jtxa.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
                {
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me)
                    {
                        if(me.getClickCount()==2) //making sure there was a double click
                        {
                            int x = me.getX();
                            int y = me.getY();

                            int startOffset = jtxa.viewToModel(new Point(x, y));//where on jtextarea click was made
                            String text = jtxa.getText();
                            int searchHttp = 0;
                            int wordEndIndex = 0;
                            String[] words = text.split("\\s");//spliting the text to words. link will be a single word

                            for(String word:words)
                            {
                                if(word.startsWith("https://") || word.startsWith("http://"))//looking for the word representing the link
                                {
                                    searchHttp = text.indexOf(word);
                                    wordEndIndex = searchHttp+word.length();
                                    if(startOffset>=searchHttp && startOffset<=wordEndIndex)//after the link word was found, making sure the double click was made on this link
                                    {
                                        try
                                        {
                                            jtxa.select(searchHttp, wordEndIndex);
                                            desk.browse(new URI(word)); //opening the link in browser. Desktop desk = Desktop.getDesktop();
                                        }
                                        catch(Exception e)
                                        {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }

                                    }
                                }
                            }                           
                        }

                    }
                });
```

Comment: May be you could elaborate a little more about the crucial point in your answer. This can make it possible easier to understand for others.