# how to display string as URI in java

Tags: java

I am a beginner in Java, I am trying to build a chatbot. The query and responses are hard coded in 2D string array chatbot[][].

This is the complete code that I have used, Two objects for JTextArea 'input and dialogue ' has been used. Object input has been attached to JPanel and is used to get the text from the user and then this is searched in the 2D string array.If it is found then the response is thrown from the same array.

Now my requirement is when the response is any URL it should be displayed as a link so that user can directly click and go to the site(http://google.com for the current scenario).Kindly suggest how this can be achieved or any modification in code is required. addText is the method that is defined to add entire conversation to dialogue text area which is non editable.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

import java.awt.event.KeyListener; 
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.lang.Math;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

public class test implements KeyListener{

JFrame j=new JFrame("Temenos ChatBot");
JPanel p=new JPanel();
JTextArea dialog=new JTextArea(20,50); //it will contain the whole conversation(non editable)
JTextArea input=new JTextArea(1,50); //where we user input our query(editable)
JScrollPane scroll=new JScrollPane( 
    dialog,
    JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
    JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER
);


String[][] chatbot={

{"hi","hello","hola","ola","howdy"}, //check for query
{"hi","hello","hey"}, //provides output of the query

{"google","provide link for google","www.google.com"}, //Query
{"http://google.com"}, //response


//default 
{"we can't find your query",
"(Sorry, we could not understand)"}
};


public static void main(String[]args){
    new test();
}

private void icon(){
    j.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("dy1MzZ-W.png")));//change the icon, paste the icon in default package
}

public test(){

    j.setSize(600,400);
    j.setResizable(false);
    j.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    dialog.setEditable(false);
    input.addKeyListener(this);     

    p.add(scroll);
    p.add(input);
    p.setBackground(new Color(0,150,255));
    j.add(p);

    j.setVisible(true);
    icon();
}
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
        input.setEditable(false); 
        //-----grab quote-----------
        String quote=input.getText(); //takes whatever text user is inputting
        input.setText("");
        addText("->You:\t"+quote); 
        quote.trim(); 
        while(
            quote.charAt(quote.length()-1)=='!' ||
            quote.charAt(quote.length()-1)=='.' ||
            quote.charAt(quote.length()-1)=='?'
        ){
            quote=quote.substring(0,quote.length()-1); 
        }
        quote.trim();
        byte response=0; //byte is data type that will check for response
        /*
        0:we're searching through chatBot[][] for matches
        1:we didn't find anything
        2:we did find something
        */
        //-----check for matches----
        int j=0;//which group we're checking
        while(response==0){
            if(inArray(quote.toLowerCase(),chatbot[j*2])){
                response=2;
                int r=(int)Math.floor(Math.random()*chatbot[(j*2)+1].length);
                addText("\n->A.I.sha:\t"+chatbot[(j*2)+1][r]); 
            }
            j++;
            if(j*2==chatbot.length-1 && response==0){
                response=1;
            } //if it has come to end then set response to 1
        }

        //-----default--------------
        if(response==1){
            int r=(int)Math.floor(Math.random()*chatbot[chatbot.length-1].length);
            addText("\n->A.I.sha:\t"+chatbot[chatbot.length-1][r]); 
        }
        addText("\n");
    }
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
    if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
        input.setEditable(true);
    }
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){}

public void addText(String str){
    dialog.setText(dialog.getText()+str);
}//it will add whatever text dialogue box is having

public boolean inArray(String in,String[] str){
    boolean match=false;
    for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++){
        if(str[i].equals(in)){
            match=true;
        } //Searches for string 'in' in string array,if it finds return true
    }
    return match;
}
 }
```

Comment: Displayed where? Is this console, web, desktop application?

Comment: It will be displayed in Jpanel. I have used JTextArea to display the responses to user

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001001/how-can-i-add-a-clickable-url-in-a-jtextarea

Comment: Do you have a GUI for the display?

Comment: I have provided the complete code for reference. Kindly provide valuable suggestion how this can be achieved.

Comment: You can do this easily with `JTextArea`. It provides a callback when you click the link. Unfortunately it is 20 years since I did this and I have completely forgotten the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're making a GUI in swing, you could follow another stack overflow answer, such as this one
[How to add hyperlink in JLabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527719/how-to-add-hyperlink-in-jlabel)

Or, you could just have java open the browser to that webpage:

```
 // Create Desktop object
 Desktop d=Desktop.getDesktop();
 // Browse a URL, say google.com
 d.browse(new URI("http://google.com"));
```

Comment: I went through the link provided, did not resolved my query. I have updated the complete code, can you please suggest the modification required or any workaround for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the parse static method from Uri

```
Uri myUri = Uri.parse("http://google.com")
```

Comment: Yes, but the query and responses are in 2D string array, can't use Uri in array, is there some other method where we can highlight the particular response as Uri.